# Prevent hiding for cytoscape qtip

Tags: events, qtip2, cytoscape.js

I'm using the [Cytoscape Qtip extension](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip) to display qtips when you click nodes.

Usually you can prevent qtips from hiding when with the `hide: false` option. When this is used, you can still hide the qtips if it has a button.

However, when using cytoscape, this appears to not work. When clicking else where, a hide event will be triggered.

```
cy.elements().qtip({
    content: function(event, api){
        api.set('content.button', true);
        return 'Example qTip on ele ' + this.id();
    },
    position: {
        my: 'top center',
        at: 'bottom center'
    },
    hide: false,
    style: {
        classes: 'qtip-bootstrap',
        tip: {
            width: 16,
            height: 8
        }
    }

    events: {
              hide: function(event, api){
                 console.log(event);
              }
    }
});
```

I can prevent the hide event from following through with `event.preventDefault()`, but this will also stop the the close button from hiding the event, which is a bit messy.

Any idea while it's behaving this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleanest solution I've found is to give a garbage event for the hide event.

Using `null`, `false` or `""` all don't seem to work.

```
hide: {
    event: "asdf" //garbage event to allow hiding on close button click only
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the quick and dirty to make this work (closes on button close only) if you need it:

```
    events:{
            hide: function(event, api){


                    if(event.originalEvent.target.parentElement.parentElement.id != this[0].id){
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }

    }
```

**Explanation:**

- Any mouse clicks will trigger a hide event all visible qtips.
- We look at target of that mouse click (`event.originalEvent.target.parentElement.parentElement.id`) to see it close box of the qtip that is currently try to close. If it's not then we `preventDefault()`.

This is potentially pretty bed performance wise, because it run these `preventDefault()` for every open qtip on every mouse click.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that because this wraps Qtip on non-DOM elements, bindings to Cytoscape graph elements must be made.  These bindings are outside of the DOM and outside of Qtip's control (for example, [the hide case](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip/blob/2.2.5/cytoscape-qtip.js#L269)).

Did you try setting the hide event to the empty string `""`?

Comment: An empty string doesn't work, but a garbage string (`'asdf'`) does. :)

Comment: I think this should address it https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip/issues/12